# Dropdown list to appear outside div

Tags: css

I have a main horizontal menu inside a div. I want the dropdown menu to appear right underneath the div. Now it just expands the div when the dropdown is visible. How can I make the dropdown go outside the div?

Comment: code pls? do you mind to share

Comment: try with the div `position:relative` and the dropdown menus `position:absolute`.

Comment: I wonder sometimes, why everyone comments the same thing? When you see a comment which you feel is good, just upvote it instead of commenting the same thing again and again

Comment: Position:absolute worked, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with the div `position:relative` and the dropdown menus `position:absolute`

**HTML**

```
<div class="drop-down-container">

<div class="drop-down">

  //Your drop-down code


</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.drop-down-container
{
position:relative;
}

.drop-down
{
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of info given in the question...

Here are some things to check if I understand your question

1. try and use Z-index to see if that will help your rendering issue.
2. Another is set overflow to visible ( you might be dropping down into a div that has overflow hidden)

In my opinion though, I would suggest throwing code into questions in the future :D best of luck!!